# undefined reference to operator<< overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing a simple complex number C++ implementation as practice for overloading `operator`s. One of the operators I simply cannot get past is `<<`. I get an undefined reference error to it whenever I try to call it. [Here](https://gist.github.com/robbie0630/0e4f5f884f899e2d7d8c595cb4bbdaf9) is a gist link to my code. I am compiling it with the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp complex.cpp -Wall -Wextra -o complex
```

In addition to the unused parameter warning in `main()`, I get the following:

```
/tmp/cc7qVwEF.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& rob::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, rob::Complex const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: _unused parameter_ is _typically_ a warning, not an error. Please provide [mcve]. Most likely you didn't provide a definition for your operator overload.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Whoops, sorry! I did mean warning. Also, if you check the code, I did provide a definition.

Comment: There is no [mcve] in the question. All the relevant code should be present in the question itself, and not in external links.

Comment: Templated functions and methods can't be compiled separately. Move the definition of `operator<<` into the header file.